LogLogPlot Issue with BesselJ in Mathematica
I am trying to create a LogLogPlot in Mathematica for the following function:
LogLogPlot[BesselJ[1, 10^12/T], {T, 10^5, 10^7}]

However, the resulting plot appears distorted (see attached image). It seems there might be numerical instability or domain issues causing this behavior.

Is this a numerical precision issue due to the argument of BesselJ being very large?
Are there better approaches to handle such cases or to improve the accuracy of the plot?

Any suggestions or insights would be appreciated!


Negative values cannot be plotted with LogLogPlot. And BesselJ does change its sign.

Would this be an adequate display:  ``LogLinearPlot[BesselJ[1, 10^12/T], {T, 10^5, 10^7}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, PlotPoints -> 200].  Even ignoring taking the log of a negative value, the range of values for the vertical axis isn't large enough to warrant a log transformation.

In addition to @JimB’s excellent advice, you might want to do this: ‘LogLinearPlot[BesselJ[1, 1/T], {T, 10^7,10^5},WorkingPrecision -> 100, PlotPoints -> 200],

At the arguments that you are interested in, the Bessel functions can be approximated by asymptotic expressions extremely well. For instance, Asymptotic[BesselJ[1, z], z -> ∞] gives $\frac{3\sin z}{8\sqrt{\pi}z^{3/2}}+\frac{3\cos z}{8\sqrt{\pi}z^{3/2}}+\frac{\sin z}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{z}}-\frac{\cos z}{\sqrt{\pi}\sqrt{z}}$, with the dominant term being $J_1(z)\approx\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi z}}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-z\right)$ as given in various math textbooks. This asymptote will show you exactly what is happening at large $z$ and likely provides more understanding than your log-log plot.
